# Unable to see 'maven dependencies' in my parent maven project but I can see these in both child modules

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a maven project and two maven modules.In build path, I am unable to see the 'maven dependencies' in my parent project but i can see these in both modules.

How can i include the maven dependencies in my eclipse build path. I have tried answers from similar questions on this site, but still I can't resolve this.

I have tried

1. clean project
2. update maven dependencies

I even re-imported from git, but unable to get the solution. How can I get maven dependencies under my project?

Comment: Do you have any dependencies in your parent pom? Can you post the pom.xml for the parent and child projects here?

Comment: yes, i have lot of dependencies in parant pom.

Comment: Parent dependencies are inherited by child modules, but parent should have "pom packaging", so it has no sense that eclipse configure a classpath for the parent artifact... or am I missing something?

Comment: parent has pom packaging.